# Python - Make One Turtle Object Always Above Another

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I would like to create a program where one Turtle object always stays above all of the other Turtle objects. I don't know if this is possible, but any help would be apprecated.

This is my code:

```
from turtle import *
while True:
    tri = Turtle()
    turtle = Turtle()
    tri.pu()
    tri.pencolor("white")
    tri.color("black")
    tri.shape("turtle")
    tri.bk(400)
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.pencolor("white")
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.speed(0)
    tri.speed(0)
    turtle.shapesize(100,100,00)
    setheading(towards(turtle))
    while tri.distance(turtle) > 10:
        turtle.ondrag(turtle.goto)
        tri.setheading(tri.towards(turtle))
        tri.fd(5)
    clearscreen()
```

Comment: on a tangential note: The only purpose I could think of for turtle was to reminiscence over the logo days. :D Not that it is a problem

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do all the drawing for the "bottom" turtle first?  Then do the drawing for the "top" turtle?  This should make the top turtle always visible.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. Thanks though. The problem is that whenever I drag the "bottom" Turtle somewhere, it goes to the top, and covers the "top" Turtle.

Answer (score 0):

My Observed Rules of Turtle Layering:

- Multiple Turtles moving to same location: *last to arrive is on top.*
- Same thing drawn by multiple turtles: *there are no rules!*

To illustrate my second point, consider this code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

a = Turtle(shape="square")
a.color("red")
a.width(6)
b = Turtle(shape="circle")
b.color("green")
b.width(3)

b.goto(-300, 0)
b.dot()
a.goto(-300, 0)
a.dot()

a.goto(300, 0)
b.goto(300, 0)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Run it and observe the result.  On my system, the final `goto()` draws a long green line over the red one but the green line disappears as soon as it has finished drawing.  Comment out the two calls to `dot()` and observe again.  Now the green line remains over the red one.  Now change the calls from `dot()` to `stamp()` or `circle(5)` instead.  Observe and formulate your own rule...

Now back to your example, which is badly flawed (you're actually manipulating three turtles, not two!)  Here's my simplification:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

tri = Turtle(shape="turtle")
tri.color("black")
tri.pu()

turtle = Turtle(shape="square")
turtle.shapesize(4)
turtle.color("pink")
turtle.pu()

def drag_handler(x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.ondrag(drag_handler)

turtle.ondrag(drag_handler)

tri.bk(400)
while tri.distance(turtle) > 10:
    tri.setheading(tri.towards(turtle))
    tri.fd(5)

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

You can tease `tri` by dragging the pink square until `tri` catches up with it.  Ultimately, `tri` will land on top as long as the square isn't moving when `tri` catches it.  If you drag the square over `tri`, then it will temporarily cover him as it is the "last to arrive".