# Python Turtle Graphics - Bring A Turtle To The Front

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have two turtles in my program. An animation happened where they collide together, but I would like one turtle to be on top of the other like this:

[image: Visual Image]

So, my question is - how can I make this happen - is there a simple line of code such as: `turtle.front()`, if not what is it?

Comment: I think if you will draw turtle 1 after drawing turtle 2, yellow will be rendered above blue automatically

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score 3):

I discuss this briefly in my response to [Make one turtle object always above another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160615/python-make-one-turtle-object-always-above-another/41067307#41067307) where the rule of thumb for this simple situation is:

> *last to arrive is on top*

Since Python turtle doesn't optimize away zero motion, a simple approach is to move the turtle you want on top by a zero amount:

```
import turtle

def tofront(t):
    t.forward(0)

gold = turtle.Turtle("square")
gold.turtlesize(5)
gold.color("gold")
gold.setx(-10)

blue = turtle.Turtle("square")
blue.turtlesize(5)
blue.color("blue")
blue.setx(10)

turtle.onscreenclick(lambda x, y: tofront(gold))

turtle.done()
```

The blue turtle overlaps the gold one.  Click anywhere and the situation will be reversed.

Although @Bally's solution works, my issue with it is that it creates a new turtle everytime you adjust the layering.  And these turtles don't go away.  Watch `turtle.turtles()` grow.  Even my solution leaves footprints in the turtle undo buffer but I have to believe it consumes less resources.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to turtle.py file

```
def tofront(self, tobring):
    newfront = tobring.clone()
    tobring.ht()
    return newfront
```

works correct, 
so method - sould return you new clone of turtle, on the top of all other turtles.
parameter tobring - it's your current turtle (the one you want to bring to front)

you can use this def in your program or put it into turtle.py file
if so, don't forget to add it to list of commands, - _tg_turtle_functions

```
_tg_turtle_functions = ['back', 'backward', 'begin_fill', 'begin_poly', 'bk',
    'circle', 'clear', 'clearstamp', 'clearstamps', 'clone', 'tofront', 'color',
```

I did it after clone command

Hope this will help you

Comment: This solution creates a new turtle every time the layering is adjusted and these turtles hang around (see `turtle.turtles()`)  I've provided a simpler alternate answer to this question that doesn't involve creating new turtles.