# Control over which turtle renders on top of another

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm currently trying to make 3d graphics using Turtle.

I have a list of objects that have inherited the Turtle class and each one has an attribute frontFactor - this value is the distance of the turtle to the camera.

How can I make the turtles closer to the camera render on top of the other turtles behind it?

My current code trying to do this:

```
finished = []
highestIndex = 0
print("FRAME")
for object in objects:
    for i in range(len(object.particles)):
        curHighest = 0
        for j in range(len(object.particles)):
            if object.particles[j].frontFactor > curHighest and (not (j in finished)):
                curHighest = object.particles[j].frontFactor
                highestIndex = j
        object.particles[highestIndex].move(0,0,0)
        print(object.particles[highestIndex].frontFactor)
        finished.append(highestIndex)
```

where objects has an attribute of particles which is a list,
and every item in this list has a value frontFactor that determines the distance to the virtual camera.

This function goes through each particle on the screen (currently i only have one object), starting from the particles farthest away from the camera and ending at the particles nearest the camera.

[image: This is what I want to happen] This is what I want to happen,

[image] but this is what it looks like instead. (darker particles are further away)

I've heard of a rule which states "last to move is on top" although I don't know how to implement that in this situation.

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41067307/5771269) I set down my two  rules for turtle layering, the first of which is "last to arrive is on top", and the second, regarding drawing, should be reviewed as well.  In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43289505/5771269) I provide a practical example of how to force a turtle to the fore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle Graphics - Bring A Turtle To The Front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086100/python-turtle-graphics-bring-a-turtle-to-the-front)