# Sequence of objects in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've drawn two objects in Python turtle, when the second object draws on screen, it comes in front of the first object and hides it. I don't want that, I want the first object to come in front. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could gather your objects into a list and draw them in [reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python):

```
a = [ ... ] # objects that respond to draw
for i in reversed(a):
    i.draw()
```

Comment: these are actually two images.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The rule when it comes to two turtle objects at the same location is: ***last to arrive is on top***

There are (random) exceptions, see [my answer to *Make One Turtle Object Always Above Another.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41067307/5771269)

> these are actually two images.

Assuming your images are turtles, via `turtle.register_shape()` (or its alias) and `turtle.shape()`, then you may be able to force the rear image/turtle to the front, even if drawn first, by making it do some sort of null motion, eg. `turtle.forward(0)`, forcing it to arrive *later*.